# best way for saving settings to external storage?

Tags: java, android

In My app I want to have an external file for saving my settings, item tags , etc. (for using it in outside of app like sending it on another device and so on).

after researching a lot I came to have a text file like this:

settings.txt

```
"Item1" : "data1"
"Item2" : "data2"
...
```

now is it the best solution for my purpose?

and if it is, how am I supposed to get my data based on it's id (Item number) from this kind of text file? (I can do the writing part but have no idea how to retrieve it).

Thanks in Advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of your way, you can store the `key` and `values` in `JSON` format. That way it would be easier for you to parse the data and get the value based on the item number (key). You can even use Google's [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) lib o make things simpler. [JSON.simple example – Read and write JSON](http://www.mkyong.com/java/json-simple-example-read-and-write-json/) will help as well.

Comment: I will give a shot for json and will be back here for any problem or question. thanks though.